# Highcharts: How to load data from JSON to xAxis.categories and series.data?

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

Sorry for the beginner question.

This is how my JSON looks like:

```
[
   ["junior college", "Primary", "secondary", "polytechnic"],
   ["4", "3", "1", "1"]
]
```

And this is my HTML,

```
var chart; // global
var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        defaultSeriesType: 'bar'
    },
    title:{
        text: 'No. Schools for different levels'
    },
    xAxis:{
        title:'Education Level',
        categories:[]
    },
    yAxis:{
        title:{
            text:'No. Of Schools'
        }
    },
    series:[{
        name: "No. Schools",
        data: []
    }]
};

$.getJSON('loadData.php', function(JSONresult) {
    yData = options.series[0].data; //Array to store data for y column
    xData = options.xAxis.categories; //Array to store data for x column

    xDataObj = JSONresult[0];
    yDataObj = JSONresult[1];

    for(var key in xDataObj){
        xData.push(xDataObj[key]);
    }

    for(var key in yDataObj){
        yData.push(parseFloat(yDataObj[key]));
    }
```

I tried to execute the code, firebug shows no error but the chart never shows up. Could you help point out where did I go wrong?

Comment: Is there something missing from your code? It looks like you never actually create a new instance of your chart.

Comment: @NT3RP sorry, i forgot to put the instantiate code here, i did initialize it with `chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);` but the chart never shows up. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the solution.

In my php script, I have to cast integer to the series data,

```
(int)$variable;
```

so the JSON out put would be

```
[4, 3, 1, 1]
```

and the chart will be rendered.

Thank you ppl :)

Comment: Glad you found a solution; please mark your solution as accepted so others know what worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this to instantiate and render the chart:

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

This could go at the end of your getJSON response function.